# How can I inflate a View subclass from XML?

Tags: android, xml, view, subclass, inflate

I am currently populating an `Adapter` on startup with views inflated from XML using

```
private void addView(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_tile, this, null);
    mViews.add(view);
}
```

However, I've found that storing the views in a list inside the `AdapterView` creates problems with controls within those views, so I want to change over to use the recycling functions in `Adapter#getView(int position, View recycle, ViewGroup container)`.

For this reason I want to use a custom view class so I can do a sanity check (`if(recycle!=null && recycle instanceof CustomView)`) before I repopulate it in the adapter.  However, I can't find out how you inflate a custom view class from XML.  I can find out how you *add* an inflated view to a custom view, I can find out how you insert a custom view into an XML layout, etc, and obviously I am quite happily inflating these things directly using `LayoutInflater`, but I can't find an equivalent for generating the custom view itself.  I want to reuse the XML I already have; consequently I don't want to program in the elements (and how they look) directly.

Comment: By the way, I'll be astonished if this question isn't a duplicate of something, but I've looked through around twenty questions and they all seem to be slightly different.  I think the questions about "inflation" and "custom views" might need systematic retitling.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you could go

`XmlPullParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.layout.deal_tile);`
`AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);`
`View view = new CustomView(context, attributes);`

or would that be cumbersome?

Comment: I usually do the sanity check like this: `if (recycle == null || recycle.getId() != R.layout.deal_tile)`. If that evaluates to `true`, the layout needs to be inflated again.

Comment: Still curious about the original question mind you, but it does solve my immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to create my own slide gallery, i think it would help.

```java
    LinearLayout internalWrapper = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    internalWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    internalWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    addView(internalWrapper);
    this.mItems = items;
    LinearLayout generalLayout = new LinearLayout(this.getContext());

    generalLayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this.getContext(), R.layout.galleryrow, null);

    // inside linear layout
    LinearLayout generalLinear = (LinearLayout) generalLayout.findViewById(R.id.rowgenerallin);
    // set height & width to the LINEAR
    generalLinear.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(reference_width, reference_height));

    ImageView ivl = (ImageView) generalLayout.findViewById(R.id.arrow_left);
    ImageView ivr = (ImageView) generalLayout.findViewById(R.id.arrow_right);
    internalWrapper.addView(generalLayout);
```

In my case, `R.layout.gallery_row` contains the two images I want to manage, nested by a `LinearLayous (rowgenerllin)`, the internal wrapper is an empty `LinearLayout` declared in the main layout of your activity. 
Double check the LayoutParams code or you will get a big NULL :)

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, as i said i was using this piece to create another thing, just extrapolate it with one LinearLayout less.

Comment: This is how I am doing it at the moment; I need to be able to make a subclass of `View`, though, using the same layout file (ideally) so I can then use the recycled view parameter in `Adapter#getView(int pos, View recycle, ViewGroup ctr)`

Comment: so the next step may be to implement the initalization logic of the adapter's getView() method to load the custom layout or recycle it, sounds fun!

Comment: I've already done that bit.  I want to put the custom XML into a custom view class so I can simply repopulate the various fields, knowing that I've been supplied the correct type of view.